# I am not able to access the values ​in try catch

Tags: android, json, try-catch

I have three values ​​to send to MainActivity. the JSONObject json is arriving with the correct value, but this value is not being accessed in try catch, that is, the onPostExecute is only executing pDialog.dismiss () ;.

how do I get the onPostExecute to read internally the try cartch?

MainActivity

```
package ic.eng.br.testejson;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Json{

    EditText edtUsuario, edtSenha;
    Button btnLogin;
    TextView textView1, textView2, textView3;

    JSONArray user = null;

    String url = "http://www.ic.eng.br/android/login.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edtUsuario = findViewById(R.id.edtUsuario);
        edtSenha = findViewById(R.id.edtSenha);
        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView3 = findViewById(R.id.textView3);


        final Asyncexecute asyncexecute = new Asyncexecute(this, this);


    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String usuario = edtUsuario.getText().toString();
            String senha = edtSenha.getText().toString();

            asyncexecute.execute(usuario, senha, url, "");

        }
    });


    }

public void testejson (String Rsenha, String Rprivilegio, String Rperfil) {

            textView1.setText(Rsenha);
            textView2.setText(Rprivilegio);
            textView3.setText(Rperfil);


}

}
```

Asyncexecute:

```
package ic.eng.br.testejson;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class Asyncexecute extends AsyncTask <String, String, JSONObject> {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private Context context;

    JSONArray user = null;

    String Rsenha, Rprivilegio, Rperfil;

    String usuario, senha, url;

    private static final String TAG_USER = "usuario";

    private Json execinterface;

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";


    public Asyncexecute(Context context,  Json execinterface) {
        this.execinterface = execinterface;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setMessage("Carregando");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();


    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        usuario = params[0];
        senha = params[1];
        url = params[2];

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);;

        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        pDialog.dismiss();

        try {
             user = json.getJSONArray("login");
             JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);

            Rsenha = c.getString("senha");
             Rprivilegio = c.getString("privilegio");
             Rperfil = c.getString("perfil");
             execinterface.testejson(Rsenha, Rprivilegio, Rperfil);

         } catch (JSONException e){
             e.printStackTrace();

         }

    }


}
```

JSONParser:

```
package ic.eng.br.testejson;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "tiago"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("senha", "123456"));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Joson

```
package ic.eng.br.testejson;

import android.view.View;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public interface Json {

    void testejson (String Rsenha, String Rprivilegio, String Rperfil);
}
```

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtUsuario"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColor="#D3D3D3"
        tools:ignore="Autofill,LabelFor,TextFields"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxywzç"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtSenha"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="15" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Efetuar Login"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: what does the execinterface.testejson method ?

Comment: How does your json look?

Comment: the execinterface.testejson (Rsenha, Rprivilegio, Rperfil); is in an interface ``` public void testejson (String Rsenha, String Rprivilegio, String Rperfil) {

            textView1.setText(Rsenha);
            textView2.setText(Rprivilegio);
            textView3.setText(Rperfil);


} ```

Comment: Are you using context?

Comment: yes, put the complete code ...